# SiteCore Workflow - Reject to a specific state

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

Taking the example of the Sample Workflow in SiteCore, in the Approving state state, can I add a new Reject option for the approver to reject the item and move it to the reviewing state?

I believe that the default reject action in any state will always move the item back to the first/draft state but we are implementing a workflow with multiple states in it and the approver would like to have the option to reject to the various teams which each have a state in the workflow. So, is it possible to have multiple reject options as well - for example, can the approver reject to draft or to reviewing based on the error detect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the 'Reject' item underneath your approving workflow step, then set the 'Next State' field to point to the correct workflow state.

Comment: Many thanks! I've just updated the question to add one more query which is to be able to configure multiple reject options in a state. To be able to reject to different teams based on the error detected by the approver.

Comment: @user3093508 in your workflow definition, just add multiple actions - each with a different 'next state' value as per Jason's answer below

Answer (score 3):

In order to have the choice to reject to multiple different states, you will need to add multiple reject buttons. Simply duplicate the Reject "Command" item, point each items "Next State" field to a diff state, and then rename the "Command" items accordingly so the user knows what they mean. E.G. "Reject to Draft" and "Reject to Reviewing".